# SQL CASE and local variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to know how I can use local variables in `CASE` statements in SQL?

This script gives me an error:

```
    DECLARE @Test int;
    DECLARE @Result char(10);
    SET @Test = 10;

    CASE @Test
    WHEN @Test = 10
    THEN SET @Result='OK test'
    END
    Print @Result;
```

I use MS SQL 2008.

Comment: Did they drop the "Server" part of the name? ;-P

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Two ways to use CASE in this scenario with MSSQL

```
DECLARE 
    @test   int,
    @result char(10)

SET @test = 10

SET @result = CASE @test
    WHEN 10 THEN 
        'OK test'
    ELSE
        'Test is not OK'
END

PRINT @result;

SET @result = CASE 
    WHEN @test = 10 THEN 
        'OK test'
    ELSE
        'Test is not OK'
END

PRINT @result
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
DECLARE @Test int;
DECLARE @Result char(10);
SET @Test = 10;

select @Result=
CASE @Test
WHEN 10 THEN  'OK test'
END

Print @Result;
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server I would write it like this:

```
DECLARE @Test int;
DECLARE @Result char(10);
SET @Test = 10;

SET @Result = CASE @Test
WHEN 10
 THEN 'OK test'
END
Print @Result;
```

The `WHEN` clause does not have `@Test = 10`, as the `@Test` variable is stated in the `CASE` clause.

See the [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) documentation for SQL Server.

Comment: This does not work in my SQL 2005 db. (incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Case'). (I had the same solution, but it didn't work).

Comment: The syntax here is wrong. You can't use a case statement like an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

CASE @Test WHEN 10 THEN

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Test int;
SET @Test = 10;

SELECT 
CASE @Test
WHEN 10
THEN 'OK test'
END
```

For SQL server 2005

Comment: anishmarokey's answer is a bit cleaner as it retains your @result variable.